# mongodb update field a to be value of field b

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run a mongo query to update the value of one field with the value of another field. I have the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d5"), "old" : 16, "new" : 17 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d3"), "old" : 11, "new" : 12 }
```

I would like to make it look like this after update:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d5"), "old" : 16, "new" : 16 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d3"), "old" : 11, "new" : 11 }
```

I've tried the following with no luck

```
db.runCommand(
{
 findAndModify: "testData",
 query: { $where: "this.new != this.old" },
 update: { old : this.new },
 upsert: true
}
)
```

and

```
db.testData.update( { $where: "this.new != this.old" }, { $set: { old: this.new } } );
```

Is this even possible with mongoDb?

I would like to do it in a single query and not iterate through each document.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this and probably change `_id` when you want to update other document:

```
db.testData.find().forEach(function(elem) {
  db.testData.update({
    "_id": "56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d5"
  }, {
    $set: {
      new: elem.old
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I did not want to iterate through all products. Thank you for response though

Comment: you can use `limit(1)` to get only one elem.

Comment: @Bun where would you put the `limit(1)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in MongoDB yet (note to visitors from the future: I'm referring to V3.2).

You have to iterate on the documents.

NB there's a trick in case you don't mind deleting the `old` field: use [rename](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) to rename `old` to `new`.

NB2 for some SQLike-fu actions (not this one) the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) can be useful.

Comment: You're welcome, NB I've added an info (just in case).

Comment: using aggregation - please see my answer

Comment: @Ilya thanks for you input - there was no duplicates at end, but... collection was cropped only to matched documents - so $out overwrites collection - which I was not aware of this behavior.  Decided to delete my answer to avoid surprises

Comment: I see. You answer as actually useful (I think), maybe not for that exact case, but for some related or other SQL-like needs like joins, but that's your call.